# why after I connect to sql server with library golang go-mssqldb, it prints <nil>?

Tags: go, go-gin

After I connect to sql server, it prints `<nil>` , what is wrong with my code or is there a problem with my connection to sql server because they just print `<nil>`?

Error screenshot:

[image]

```golang
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "net/http"
)

func main()  {
    db, err :=  sql.Open("sqlserver","sqlserver://sa:@localhost:1433?database=CONFINS&connection+timeout=30")
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Print(err.Error())
    }


    err = db.Ping()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err.Error())
    }
    defer db.Close()

    type SMSBlast struct {
        SequenceID  string
        MobilePhone string
        Output  string
        WillBeSentDate string
        SentDate string
        Status string
        DtmUpd string
    }

    router := gin.Default()

    //Get a SMSBlast  detail
    router.GET("/SMSBlast2/:SequenceID", func(context *gin.Context) {
        var(
            smsblast SMSBlast
            result gin.H
        )

        SequenceID := context.Param("SequenceID")
        fmt.Println(db.Ping())
        row := db.QueryRow("select SequenceID, MobilePhone, Output, WillBeSentDate, SentDate, Status, DtmUpd from SMSBlast2 = ?;",SequenceID)
        err = row.Scan(&smsblast.SequenceID, &smsblast.MobilePhone, &smsblast.Output, &smsblast.WillBeSentDate, &smsblast.SentDate, &smsblast.Status, &smsblast.DtmUpd)
        if err != nil{
            //if no results send null
            result = gin.H{
                "result": nil,
                "count":  0,
            }
            }else{
                result = gin.H{
                    "result" : smsblast,
                    "count" : 1,
                }
            }

        context.JSON(http.StatusOK, result)
    })
    router.Run(":8080")

}
```

Comment: Who's "they" and where do they return that? SQL, the language, not just SQL Server, doesn't have `nil`. *Your* code though seems to return that value in case of error, without even checking what that error is

Comment: Aren't you missing `WHERE SequenceID = ?` in your sql string? Anyway that's just a guess, you should really just log the error that's returned from `row.Scan`, that way you'll know what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @mkopriva I have correct that code with   row := db.QueryRow("select SequenceID, MobilePhone, Output, WillBeSentDate, SentDate, Status, DtmUpd from SMSBlast2 where SequenceID = ?;",SequenceID) , but still display nil

Comment: @DevoAvidiantoPratama it's *your* code that does that, if there's any error. You should modify your code to at least log the error, not just return an emtpy result. You already had a syntax error that would prevent your query from running. The error message would have explained that.

Comment: @DevoAvidiantoPratama test the query using SSMS or ADS or any other database client tool you want before you write your code. If you can't run a query directly, you won't be able to run it using your own code

Comment: I test my query in SSMS , query is working , but after implementing in code is not display json @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>     fmt.Println(db.Ping())
> ```

Prints the error returned by `db.Ping()`, which normally is `nil`.

Comment: that correct thank you , I forget to delete db.ping()